# How to request JSON among three tables

Tags: sql, json, sql-server

Suppose I have 3 tables `employee`, `child` and `employee_child`.

The first table contains `id` and `name` columns, the second contains `id` and `name` as well, and in the last contains `id`, `employee_id`, `child_id`.

Those tables (`employee` and `child`) are associated in the table `employee_child`.

To help, I let these queries to populate those tables:

```
CREATE TABLE employee (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(128))

INSERT INTO employee(id, name)
VALUES(1, 'Josh'), (2, 'Michel'), (3, 'Will')

CREATE TABLE child (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(128))

INSERT INTO child(id, name)
VALUES(1, 'Karen'), (2, 'Adam'), (3, 'Ellen')

CREATE TABLE employee_child (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
employee_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
child_id INTEGER NOT NULL)

ALTER TABLE employee_child ADD FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employee (id)
ALTER TABLE employee_child ADD FOREIGN KEY (child_id) REFERENCES child (id)

INSERT INTO employee_child(id, employee_id, child_id)
VALUES(1, 1, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 2, 3)
```

[Results of selects from tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5TmS.png)

I need to get the employee's name and his child's names by `employee.id` using JSON request, and get the following answer:

```
{
   "id":1,
   "name":"Josh",
   "children":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Karen"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"Adam"
      }
   ]
}
```

I've tried another way, but the most right answer that I got was this following query:

```
SELECT [''] = (SELECT e.id, e.name
               FROM employee e
               WHERE e.id = 1
               FOR JSON PATH), 
       [children] = (SELECT c.id, c.name
                     FROM child c
                     INNER JOIN employee_child ec ON ec.child_id= c.id
                     WHERE ec.employee_id = 1
                     FOR JSON PATH)
FOR JSON PATH
```

I'd like to get a support to achieve the fully answer.

Comment: Sample data will help us help you. It's no good telling us what your expected results are if we don't know what your existing data looks like.

Comment: So thankful about your advice! I added some data in the question, will it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FOR JSON AUTO` seems to get you exactly what you want:

```sql
SELECT e.id,
       e.name,
       children.id,
       children.name
FROM dbo.employee e
     JOIN dbo.employee_child ec ON e.id = ec.employee_id
     JOIN dbo.child children ON ec.child_id = children.id
WHERE e.id = 1
FOR JSON AUTO;
```

Comment: Thank you! Your answer helped me a lot!